# Hydra fails with "[ERROR] target ssh://192.168.16.128:22/ does not support password authentication."?

Tags: ssh, brute-force, hydra

I've updated Kali 2.0 to newest version - it is installed using VMWare.

Now, every time I use hydra to brute-force SSH, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] target ssh://192.168.16.128:22/ does not support password authentication.
```

The corresponding command is as follows:

```
hydra -l anne -P /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt 192.168.16.128 -t 32 ssh
```

I can easily log into the SSH server  (tried a couple of servers) using ssh (`ssh anne@192.168.16.128`) and entering the password.

I really have no idea what could be wrong? Every tutorial I read on the Internet seems to work flawlessly without the issues I'm experiencing...

The complete session can be seen below:

```
root@kali:~# hydra -l anne -P /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt 192.168.16.128 -t 32 ssh
Hydra v8.6 (c) 2017 by van Hauser/THC - Please do not use in military or secret service organizations, or for illegal purposes.

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2018-04-16 19:30:56
[WARNING] Many SSH configurations limit the number of parallel tasks, it is recommended to reduce the tasks: use -t 4
[DATA] max 32 tasks per 1 server, overall 32 tasks, 14344399 login tries (l:1/p:14344399), ~448263 tries per task
[DATA] attacking ssh://192.168.16.128:22/
[ERROR] target ssh://192.168.16.128:22/ does not support password authentication.
```

Answer (score 1):

SSH supports several different authentication mechanisms. The `password` authentication mechanism has the client send the password to the server *as a password*. The more-common `keyboard-interactive` authentication mechanism opens a channel between the client and an authentication process on the server. The client allows the user to directly interact with the authentication process, which is usually just a password prompt. This allows more complex features like multiple-factor authentication and pre-authentication warnings and checks.

So your target probably supports `keyboard-interactive` and not `password` authentication.

Comment: How do I tell Hydra to use keyboard-interactive, if that is even possible?

Comment: @Shuzheng hydra is pretty out-dated and in my opinion, you can't. Anyway make sure yourself that server is using keyboard-interactive by trying to enumerate auth methods supported with: "nmap --script ssh-auth-methods IP"

Answer (score 0):

Your timing option needs to move in front of your host/protocol. Try this:

```
hydra -l anne -P /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt -t 32 ssh://192.168.16.128
```